# Execute interactive command in Hp-UX ksh (without expect) and grab child process

Tags: c, unix, scripting, ksh, hp-ux

I have to execute a unix interactive command that launches another ksh interactive shell, so I can then execute other commands.

expect or tcl/tk is not available, and it seems that I cannot play with redirects (as first interactive command launches other child that I cannot redirect (or don't know how to) outputs.

**Example (not automatted)**

```
$ /bin/someComand
username: xpto
password: xpty

someCommand is now executing other voodooshell:

voodooshell$ /bin/anotherCommand
This is the output you want..
bye
.
```

**The 1st part is simple:**

```
$ /bin/someCommand<<E
xpto
xpto

E
```

**Trying something like this does not work**

```
$ /bin/someCommand<<E
xpto
xpto


E<(otherPrettyCommands<<A
who
quit
A )
```

So i though..... c program with popen !? :-) well, that's fine to solve the 1st problem again, but how can I get the child process of the 1st problem and redirect commands to it before it quits ? :-(

How would you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture just the output (and not to inject input) maybe you can run an equivalent of Linux's

## strace -ff -p pid

and then attempt to parse the output of the strace.

For HP-UX I believe that the equivalent of strace is truss or tusc.
tusc can be downloaded at
http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/tusc-8.1/

(But I've never used tusc or truss in HP-UX, so I don't really know if this is feasable).

Comment: we need to inject commands to the created child process (some kind of ksh shell)